# how to calculate expected value of $T$'th round of sampling without replacement

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expected-value

Let's assume we have $n$ token consisting of red($R$) and blue($B$) colors with $|R|=n_1$ and $|B|=n_2$ ($n=n_1+n_2$). If we draw one token each time without replacement and repeat this process $T$ times, how many $R$ and how many $B$ tokens are expected to be drawn?

I tried to solve this but the conditional probability tree grows exponentially so that in $T$'th round I end-up with $2^T$ events (while the probability of most of them are $0$ because $r>=n_1$ or $b>=n_2$). Is there another method to solve this in less computational complexity? Also please explain how to solve a similar problem with more than two tokens.

Comment: repeating the process $n$ times mean taking all $n$tokens?

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja: I have edited the number of trials with $T$. so we have $n$ tokens ($n=n_1 + n_2$) and we draw $T$ tokens ($T<n_1+n_2$).

Comment: Imagine that all the tokens are randomly arranged in a line.  How many of the first $T$ do you expect to be red?  How many blue?

Comment: @saulspatz: I didn't understand the point of your question. I might be missing a simple point. my problem is that when we draw tokens without replacement, the probability of each draw depends (or is conditioned to) on the previous draws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k=1,\dots,T$, let $X_K$ be a random variable whose value is $1$ if draw number $k$ is red and $0$ if it is blue.  The expected number of red balls is $$E\left(\sum_{k=1}^T X_k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^TE(X_k)=\frac{Tn_1}{n_1+n_2}$$ because $E(X_k)=\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2}$ for every $k$.

What you say in a comment about the changing probability as balls are drawn is a statement about the conditional probability, but it's easier to just use linearity of expectation, as above.

If this isn't clear, imagine that instead of colored balls, we have cards with red and blue backs.  The cards are shuffled and $T$ of them are dealt face-up in a line.  What is the probability that the $k$th card in the line has a red back?

If you want to do it more formally, compute the probability that $X_2=1.$  Remember, $$\begin{align}\Pr(X_2=1)=&\Pr(X_2=1|X_1=1)\Pr(X_1=1)+\\&\Pr(X_2=1|X_1=0)\Pr(X_1=0)\end{align}$$

Comment: So, you are saying that the only way is to assume they are independent (excluding formal way which gets complex as $T$ grows)?

Comment: No, I'm not saying they are independent.  They aren't independent.  Linearity of expectation does not require independence.  I'm not ignoring anything.  To do it the way you suggest requires averaging over all possible sequences of draws.  Just work it out of $T=2$ or $T=3$ and you'll see.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried it manually with $p=0.6$ and $q=0.4$ for $T=2$ and $3$. It worked perfectly with $E_2(p)=1.2$,$E_2(q)=0.8$,$E_3(p)=1.8$ and $E_3(q)=1.2$ using both linearity of expectation and formal method.